# How to write a stored procedure, so that it will run the last column and save that in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has last column is the code. The table looks like below:

```
Rule_ID   Simple_English_Description   Source_Attribute   Dependent_Attribute   View   text
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   39     Material description Mandatory for all Material types Material Description        Basic Data
```

Code:

```
INSERT INTO GDQ_PRODUCT_ERROR_TABLE 
    SELECT 
        '39' as RULE_ID,
        vw.MATNR, VW.REGION_CODE, VW.COUNTRY_CODE, VW.[CLUSTER_CODE],
        VW.[COMMON_COUNTRY],  
        'MATERIAL DESCRIPTION' as SRC_ATTR,
        VW.MAKTX AS SOURCE_VALUE,
        '' AS WERKS,
        VW.MTART, VW.MAKTX, VW.NUMTP, VW.EAN11, VW.MEINS, VW.MSTAE, VW.PRDHA,
        CASE 
           WHEN (vw.MAKTX IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(vw.MAKTX)) = '' 
              THEN 'I' 
              ELSE 'V' 
        END as DQ_INVALID 
    FROM
        T_U2K2_ECC_MAKT_GDQ_ACTIVE vw;
```

How to write the stored procedure so that it can be a loop and read from the last column and return the output?

I have tried writing a stored procedure but it is not able to select only last column and insert the value into main table.

I have tried below code:

```
DECLARE @item CHAR(2)
DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT [text] from GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy
OPEN item_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
    SET @Query = (N'Select [text] FROM GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy')

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query

FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

END

CLOSE item_cursor
DEALLOCATE item_cursor
```

I have tried this code but here it's executing the text column not the inside value which is the original code in string format I have saved

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so we can better understand what your requirement is?

Comment: I have shared the code I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting `Select [text] FROM GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy` in quotes N'' which will actually execute the `Select [text] FROM GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy` statement itself when you execute the `@Query`.
Also, your cursor is putting the value of Text column in a char(2) @item field which will truncate the string to 2 characters. 
Try this:

```
DECLARE @item NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
FOR SELECT [text] from GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy 
OPEN item_cursor


FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Item
FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

END

CLOSE item_cursor DEALLOCATE item_cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I need to run the [text] column which contains multiple queries as string and save that value in a table

Comment: @Raya you do have the 'Insert' command as well in the stored query right?

Comment: yes I do have it..but it is not executing only last column as a query and storing the output

Comment: But can I ask for another help.. how can I store the error message in another table so that I understand where the code goes wrong?

Comment: You can use a TRY/CATCH block. But you should post a separate question for any doubts on that